# DeltaTime and transforming issue

Tags: java, game-engine, game-physics

I have a (simple) game engine; and in game loop i have a "deltaTime" variable. (The time since last frame, in seconds) The deltaTime variable is exactly as id expect.

However, even though the deltaTime is fine, i cant transform an entity's position accurately. It works fine under very low FPS, but as it get higher (15<) it breaks down, and doesn't work. The object goes very, very slowly. The faster the FPS, the slower it goes. I even tried limiting the FPS to 120.

Ive been able to find the suspected troubled code area here:

```
curEntity.pos.y+= curEntity.velocity.y * deltaTime;
```

pos.y, velocity.y, and deltaTime are all floats.

Whats the deal here? How can i fix this?

If your interested, here is the code that gets the deltaTime:

```
long now = System.nanoTime();
deltaTime= (now - lastTime) /  1000000000f;
lastTime=now;
```

// Its worth noting, i'm trying to do what Unity does;
also, i have tried chaning the pos.y, velocity.y, and deltaTime to doubles

Comment: Would it be possible to store the values of the delta time in memory and print them out at the end to see if they match with the FPS?  That is to say that at 50 FPS the deltaTime hovers at around 20ms.

Comment: @JoseMartinez Yes, and i have tried that. I used a sleep method to stall the loop and found the deltaTime variable returned exactly as i would expect. Also, the deltaTime is in seconds; so i can do 1*deltaTime (1 per second)

Comment: if `curEntity.pos.y` is big and both `curEntity.velocity.y` and `deltaTime` are really small, you might run out of precision. Then the value of `curEntity.pos.y` would stay just the same. See section Adding Large and Small Numbers [here](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Weaknesses/).

Comment: Why did you stall it? That will make your observations void. Keep deltaTime in nanos and it will run correctly, I bet.

Comment: @Fildor What i did was put the loop on a sleep.So if i put the loop to sleep for 1 second, the deltTime returned 1 (expected) if i put it to sleep for half a second, it returned .5 (expected)

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with it for awhile i found out the answer:
I had the delta-Time since the last loop pass, **not** the last physics update.
Here (if anyone cares) is the answer:

```
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        //HERE IS WHERE THE DELTA TIME CODE WAS LAST
        tickDelta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        frameDelta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerFrame;
        lastTime=now;

        if(tickDelta>=1){
            //THIS IS WHERE IT SHOULD BE
            //GETS THE TIME SINCE LAST TICK
            deltaTime= (now - deltaTimeTimer) / 1000000000f; 
            deltaTimeTimer=now;
            ticks++; Tick(); tickDelta=0;
        }
        if(frameDelta>=1){frames++; Render(); frameDelta=0;}

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - Timer >= 1){Timer+=1000; System.out.println("FPS: "+frames+"; TPS: "+ticks +"; deltaTime: "+deltaTime); ticks=0;frames=0;}

        try{Thread.sleep(5);} catch(Exception err){} //TODO: Remove
        //System.out.println(deltaTime);
    }
}
```